# Adding submit event on form prevents submit parameter from being included in HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Just what the question title says. I'm using SpringMVC, but that's irrelevant really. I just need to be able to pass the submit button `name=value` along with the rest of the form parameters for validation and control purposes. Example below for clarification:

The HTML I'm using:

```
<form action='somepage.htm' method='post'>
  <input name='somename' value='bob' />
  <input type='submit' name='mybutton' value='click me' />
</form>
```

The JavaScript (with jQuery) I'm using:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]', this).attr('disabled','disabled');
  return true;
}
```

And so the HTTP POST request looks like this without the JavaScript event binding:

`somepage.htm?somename=bob&mybutton=click%20me`

And with the bound event, it excludes the button parameter as such:

`somepage.htm?somename=bob`

I need to be able to disable the buttons and still send the button value to the server for processing.

Thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

The code I actually used to solve this problem is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    var clone = $(this).clone();
    $(clone).attr("type","hidden");
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(clone).appendTo($(this).parents('form')[0]);
    return true;
  });
});
```

And in case anyone was wondering, pressing Enter on a field in the form does in fact trigger the click event on the first submit button in the form!

Comment: The POST request cannot look like this as POST parameters are sent in the body and not in the URL. Anyway disabled form elements are not sent to the server: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12 (see 'successful').

Comment: After looking a bit more closely at my problem, I think that the actual issue is in disabling the button. I may need to reconstruct the button as a hidden field and then disable the submit button to prevent user from re-submitting the form.

Comment: @Felix: This was the best way to represent the information, not necessarily "exactly" what the request would look like. Thanks for the criticism, though. ;)

Comment: Ok :) I just wanted to make sure. Omitting the pagename and `?` would have been perfectly fine. In any case, this was just a side note ;) Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabled inputs cannot be submitted.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.12

So maybe the way to go is to add a hidden element `<input type='hidden' value='foo' name='bar'/>` to stimulate the validation methods on the other end.

Comment: This is great information, but not a full answer. Add to it and I will accept.

Comment: Just want this to be helpful to others as well, guys! Sorry for being such a slave driver! :P

Answer (score 1):

I think, if the submit button is clicked, then it's values will also be submitted, like rest of the form.